# Callback when the dropdown list of AutoCompleteView is dismissed

Tags: android, android-view

How to get a callback when the dropdown list of AutoCompleteView is dismissed in Android 4.0 and above.

Comment: `android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.OnDismissListener` added API level 17, Android 4.2, 4.2.2

Comment: Ya saw that but I have to support devices on 4.0+

Comment: so get the `AutoCompleteTextView` sources from 4.2 and try to copy them to your project